# How to calculate data between columns in powershell table

Tags: powershell

Its probably a *very* basic thing.

but i was wondering how to calculate and sum up the result in a new column.

lets say i have a variable that holds this table below

```
fresh apples     eaten
------------     -----
           2         1
          71        15
          89        32
```

---

i was wondering then, how i could calculate and present **this**:

```
fresh apples     eaten     available
------------     -----     ---------
           2         1             1 
          71        15            56
          89        32            57
```

---

Any tips or help would be **awesome :)**

Comment: What type your *variable* is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table in one single variable:

```
@”
fresh apples,eaten
2,1
7,1
89,32
“@ > C:\Informatica_POC\fruits.csv 

$fruits=import-csv C:\Informatica_POC\fruits.csv
$fruits|Select-Object 'fresh apples',eaten,@{Name='Available';Expression={$_.'fresh apples' - $_.eaten}}
```

[image]

Hope it gives you the clarity. You just need to put another column with calculations in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2)

```
$object | Select-Object -Property 'fresh apples',
                                  eaten,
                                  @{n='available';e={$_.'fresh apples' - $_.eaten}}
```